# Dynamic datalist option no showing

Tags: php, html-datalist

I'm trying to populate a datatable data dynamically with a datalist in one column using ajax server request.

From Php

```
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-clear btn-clear-datalist-dropdown"> <i class="fa fa-trash-o text-primary "></i></button>
</span>
<datalist id="dtlstTransferAcc" class="dropdown-menu-byval div-GL-list div-input-transferacc-list">
    <option class="dropdown-item" data-id="0" value="Enter  Input Tax Account  keyword in the search box and press Enter">
        <!-- dynamic list on ENTER keys-->
</datalist>
```

From the dynamic datalist I am able to send another ajax server request and populate the datalist options successfully.

Javascript

```
// target the datalist in same table row
    var div_dropitem_list = $(this).closest('.input-datalist-dropdown').find('.div-GL-list');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "js/gl.php",
        data: {
            'a': 'GL-DATA-LIST',
            'keyword': $(this).val(),
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $(div_dropitem_list).html(data);
        }
    });
```

Console log confirm the ajax data and the datalist options are populated.
[image]

However the datalist popup is not showing with the options dynamic data
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify the `value` attribute on each `option` in the `datalist`. That attribute is used to search in the list as well as providing a value to be selected in the `input` which is likely will be sent to the server.

In your case, you should have `option`s with a `value` attribute, for example: `<option value="4316 | Exchange" data-id="985" class="dropdown-item cursor-pointer">`

Here's a simple demo:

```html
<!-- to link an input with a datalist, the input must have a "list" attribute pointing to the datalist having the same "id" -->
<!-- in other words, input "list" attribute must be the same as datalist "id" -->
<label for="ice-cream-choice">Choose a flavor:</label>
<input list="ice-cream-flavors" id="ice-cream-choice" name="ice-cream-choice" />

<datalist id="ice-cream-flavors">
    <option value="Chocolate">
    <option value="Coconut">
    <option value="Mint">
    <option value="Strawberry">
    <option value="Vanilla">
</datalist>
```

> the above demo was taken from [`<datalist> Docs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist#try_it) on MDN which i recommand taking some time there to learn more about `datalist` element.

Comment: Tried the format as suggested and made combined presentation but the popup still failed.
`<datalist id="dtlstTransferAcc" class="dropdown-menu-byval div-GL-list div-input-transferacc-list">
    <option class="dropdown-item cursor-pointer" data-id="956" value="4000-Revenue">/option>
    <option class="dropdown-item cursor-pointer" data-id="834" value="2310-Seminar">2310-Seminar</option>                             
</datalist>`

Comment: @NathanDevX that is up to you on how to construct those `option`s (i only tried to provide some basic examples) but the required  attribute for your code to work as intended is the `value` attribute as I've mentioned above.

Comment: @NathanDevX what is the issue ?

Comment: The datalist option popup container with updated result is not showing

Comment: @NathanDevX are you sure the data is being populated in the `datalist` ? You didn't provide the full code nor the `HTML` part so we can't really do much but i think you should populate the element using `div_dropitem_list.html(data);`.

Comment: I figured the issue was related to input-text list attribute targeting datalist of the same Id. Appreciate the notes .

Comment: @NathanDevX kindly, if you found my answer helpful, kindly mark it as the accepted answer.